# Ag-grid Pagination on the top of the grid (Angular 2)

Tags: ag-grid

Can anyone help me to set the pagination of ag-grid both top and bottom of the grid. Right now the pagination is on the bottom of the grid, i'm trying to place on the top also. Please help me to resolve these

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is easily attainable. There is an open enhancement on the [github page](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/62) that sounds like it would allow you to do what you are trying to do.

If you wanted to create a workaround, then you could use some dom manipulation to clone what is found at the bottom. However, in my personal attempts, this proved quite difficult since the event listeners aren't cloned.

Answer (score 1):

Ag grid does not supports it. but it can be achieved by css, add below css should work for you

```css
.ag-theme-balham {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.ag-paging-panel > span {
  color: black !important;
}

.ag-root-wrapper {
  position: relative !important;
}

.ag-root-wrapper-body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ag-paging-panel {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  border-top: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one example available in ag-grid official website at below link. You can create pagination control as per your requirement and use events (onNextPage, onPrevPage).

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/